# Header is repeating in multiple pages even after choosing to display only on first page in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

I only want the header to appear on the first page of my report. I have checked a check box to display the header only on the first page but it is still repeating on every page after the first one. I am using SSRS 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

The page header is exactly what the name says - the heading for each page. The option to display the page header on the first page is *in addition* to all other pages - a lot of reports need the layout on the first page to be different to the layout of subsequent pages, so *unchecking* the display on first page option will ensure that the page header appears on all pages *except* the page header.

For anything you want to appear on only the first page of the report, simply place it at the top of the main section of the report.

Answer (score 3):

He is correct. I had a report with a tablix and I thought I could fix this by messing with the properties of the static rows in my Row Group. I thought it had something to do with there not being a page break; or the rows belonging to the before or after group.

If you have a report with 3 pages, you can actually make the page header appear on only the second page. The only two control you have over the page header are: 1) on the first page and 2) on the last page. You can't control it on the "sandwished" pages.

So, move your header content to the body of your report. That is how you can make it visible only on the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Write an expression to hide the textboxes that hold the header information.

The expression would look like this:

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber = 1, FALSE, TRUE)
```

To get to the expression property: right-click text box >> text box properties >> visibility >> select "Show or hide based on expression" >> insert expression above

[similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306092/ssrs-report-builder-only-show-header-on-first-page-with-page-numbers/16841553#16841553)