# SSRS - how to remove textbox white space on subsequent pages?

Tags: reporting-services, whitespace, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

It seems so basic and surely resolved by SSRS 2014 SP1 but I can't find a way in Print Layout (for PDF ultimately, but this is simple display) to **allow a tablix to render at the top of following pages when a text box displays above it on the first page** (eg. address details which would not be wanted on every subsequent page filled by tablix results). This results in unprofessional wasted white space above the results on every page after the first.

The tablix seems "stuck" so it only starts on the page wherever you put it on the design layout (using Report Builder because SSDT not playing with VS2015, but same things should apply). That's when the text box above it naturally doesn't even display on the subsequent pages - why would it, it's done its job and is not repeateable! After all, it's not in a header.

Have set the textbox to CanShrink=true but its still holding the space (because it's content remains, fair enough).

Also tried hiding the textbox (and should be able to do this conditionally on subsequent pages) but whitespace is still there, which is odd and perhaps shows the real limitation.

Applied ConsumeContainerWhitespace=true on report level (you would have thought that would do the trick) but no joy.

Even put both textbox and tablix in a same Rectangle so they become "peers" and maybe control the whitespace better, but nope.

Would prefer the header to repeat and the textbox address to only be on the first page, but another annoying limitation is that for headers there's only a "PrintOnFirstPage" option, not one to print on first page only! Of course, a workaround for that like [SSRS Report Builder - Only Show Header On First Page (With Page Numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306092/ssrs-report-builder-only-show-header-on-first-page-with-page-numbers) is to move textbox into the body area and hide, but as noted, that still leaves the stupid whitespace on every subsequent page - d'oh!

Surely there's a way to resolve this basic requirement, or maybe I'm missing something obvious?

EDIT: Remembered I never had this problem before and realised it's now only because there are multiple Projects per Worker (sorry, not enough rep yet for pic). If I choose a parameter period with only one project, the line descriptions will continue on the top of any subsequent pages. Only if the tablix header group (Project: [TaskDesc] and Worker) changes does a new page start - but with the tablix at the original page 1 layout location (ie under the textbox), not at the top of the subsequent page where it should be. Hope this clarifies - looks like a bug, odd tablix behaviour, but maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a non-repeating TextBox, just make sure it's outside of a repeating report element. This means outside of a Tablix or Rectangle.

Just place the TextBox at the top of your page and place the Tablix/Rectangle below it. When the Tablix/Rectangle grows beyond the maximum page height, it will break and continue at the top of a new page.

If you simply think there is too much empty space at the top of the page, try fiddling around with the page margins.

[image]

Comment: Sure @Oceans, but as noted, the TextBox is **above** the Tablix, otherwise indeed the behaviour would be expected.

Comment: I had previously added an EDIT which SE ignored for you @Oceans, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924076/ssrs-how-to-remove-textbox-white-space-before-tablix-on-subsequent-pages so it created this duplicate post. It was when I realised the buggy behaviour only occurs when a new grouping level starts - it is fine if the detail level is continuing (which does go at top of next page, not re-start at location underneath the TextBox). Will add that EDIT now.

Comment: You might have accidentally defined an group header which is adding an empty row at the start of each new group. Perhaps this might be helpful if that's the case: [How to: Display Headers and Footers with a Group (Reporting Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627600(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Turned out to be the fact that a Column Group was used (removed and fine) - can now see that they tend to fix the location of the tablix, because subsequent columns continue off on the right - best seen in normal not print layout (and comparing multiple versions in Viz Studio). So the Textboxes were red herrings, making no difference. Technically, a bug as subsequent columns should start on top of next page anyway, but almost understandable. Marking this as answer thanks @Oceans as it was all in the headers - SSRS way more fiendish than Access, DevExpress, Telerik etc!