# SSRS Page header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to display a page header only for the first page of a report and not have it repeat on subsequent pages?

I am trying to simple display the title of the report at the top of the first page and do not want it repeat. I know this is probably a simple question but kind of new to SSRS

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this question it should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306092/ssrs-report-builder-only-show-header-on-first-page-with-page-numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Report Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715263/ssrs-report-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it, you can do it with this expression. Put a textbox in the header and write the following code:

```
=IIF(Globals!OverallPageNumber = 1, "This is the header only for Page 1", Nothing)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you're after is a "Report Header".  Right-click in the gray area next to the report surface and select "add Page Header".