SSRS Header issue
I'm new to SSRS and currently working on some reports. I've set the report header to 3.5 inches and configured it to "print on the first page only." However, I notice that a 3.5-inch blank space appears on the other pages. If anyone has any suggestions for dynamically removing this extra white space from the subsequent pages, I would appreciate your help.

Any idea appreciated

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306092/ssrs-report-builder-only-show-header-on-first-page-with-page-numbers

Thanks for the reply. The header logos and other info shows only on first page as i wanted it. However,  on page 2 and above,  it show blank space on the header part. What i want was a way to remove the white space
